# In Swift, how do you get the error type from UrlSession

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, urlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have the following code in my network logic:

```
let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
  
  if let error = error {        
    if error.localizedDescription.contains("The request timed out") {
      // request timeout stuff ...
    } else {
      // other errors
    }
  }
}
```

String matching `localizedDescription` is not good code practice. How do I get the type of the error just like in `catch` clauses?

Answer (score 7):

You can cast it to a `URLError` and then look at the `code`:

```swift
if let error = error as? URLError {
    switch error.code {
    case .timedOut: ...
    case .cannotFindHost: ...
    default: ...
    }
}
```

Or you can use `if case` if there's only one case that you're concerned about:

```swift
if let error = error as? URLError, case .timedOut = error.code {
    ...
}
```

Or

```swift
if let error = error as? URLError, error.code == .timedOut {
    ...
}
```

Comment: is there any overlap between URLError categories and http response codes?

Comment: `URLError` are for failures to reach the server successfully. HTTP status codes are for when you successfully reach the server. There is no overlap. So you first check for `URLError` to see if you reached the server, and then look at the `HTTPURLResponse` to see what the server did with your request.